# How will I get a not repeating result in using `import java.util.Random`?

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans, random

Good day! I'm a beginner in programming and I've been working on a program. It uses `import java.util.Random` because I want my questions to appear randomly in no particular order. But the problem and the only problem is that the question repeats. For an instance, "Are you happy?" is asked three times and "Do you want iPhone 5?" is not even asked. What should I do to just show all the questions in no particular order and so it would not pick the same question many times? So far, this is what I have.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomQuiz {
    public static void main (String args []){
        int a, b=0;
        String arr [];
        arr = new String [5];
        a = b;
        arr [a] = "Are you happy? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment";
        a = b+1;
        arr [a] = "Did you eat breakfast? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment";
        a = b+2;
        arr [a] = "Have you watched tv? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment";
        a = b+3;
        arr [a] = "Do you want iPhone 5? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment";
        a = b+4;
        arr [a] = "Will you have iPad mini? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment";

        //prints array values in random
        Random randnum = new Random ();
        for (int count = 1; count <=5; count++){
            a = randnum.nextInt (5);
            System.out.println ("Question # " + count + "\n" + arr [a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but consider shorthand array initialization  or at least use plain old integers instead of doing math on variables--has to look at that a couple of times before I was convinced I knew what it was trying to do.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html and then iterate over array

Comment: @DaveNewton I did that because I need to assign an `int` to the array to make it random.

Comment: I meant in the array initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Random randnum = new Random (System.currentTimeMillis());
    java.util.HashSet<Integer> myset = new java.util.HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int count = 1; count <=5; count++){
        while(true)  {
            a = randnum.nextInt (5) ;
            if(!myset.contains(a)) { myset.add(new Integer(a)); break;}
        }
        System.out.println ("Question # " + count + "\n" + arr [a]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked on my program! Thanks a lot!! :D

Answer (score 5):

A truly random integer between 1 and 5 will almost certainly have a great number of repeated numbers.  If you just want to put the elements of the array in a random order, then you should use `Collections.shuffle`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] array = {
    "Are you happy? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment",
    "Did you eat breakfast? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment",
    "Have you watched tv? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment",
    "Do you want iPhone 5? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment",
    "Will you have iPad mini? \na. yes\t\tb. no\nc. maybe\td. no comment"
  };

  List<String> items = Arrays.asList(array);
  Collections.shuffle(items);

  for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    System.out.println("Question # " + (index + 1) + "\n" + items.get(index));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks good but it has errors when I pasted it on NetBeans. I also don't know how to use collections and lists yet. Are there any simpler codes than this?

Comment: @NinaDeLeon I just copied and pasted it into NetBeans and it worked fine.  Perhaps you need to fix your imports (Ctrl+Shift+I)?  This is quite frankly one of the simplest ways to do it.